# Build Windows IoT Core application based on .netcore.app 1.1.2

Tags: raspberry-pi, .net-core

I'm testing the possibilities of a raspberry pi2 and .NET Core 1.1.

If I create an application with .NET Core 1.1 and try to build it to RID "Win10-arm", I receive following error:

> Unable to resolve 'runtime.win8-arm.Microsoft.NETCore.Jit (>= 1.1.2)'
>   for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1 (win10-arm)'.

Is this something that is not supported yet?

I think this issue is similar to https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/9694 but I couldn't find any reference which stated that.

Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

can you try this?

I created an .NET Core Console App and published successfully with win10-arm

Get this Nuget Package:

```
Install-Package runtime.win8-arm.Microsoft.NETCore.Jit -Version 2.0.0-preview1-25301-02 -Pre
```

then you can build and publish.

```
:\Users\x\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\TestArm\TestArm>dotnet publish -c Release -r win10-arm
```

Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.3.117.23532
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

```
  TestArm -> C:\Users\x\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\TestArm\TestArm\bin\Release\netcoreapp1.1\win10-arm\TestArm.dll
  TestArm -> C:\Users\x\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\TestArm\TestArm\bin\Release\netcoreapp1.1\win10-arm\publish\
```